# How to protect session id and cookies without using SSL/HTTPS?

Tags: security, ssl, https

As for as I understand, if I do not use SSL/HTTPS, cookies and session ids travel as plain text over the wire. An attacher can use packet sniffer to get his hand on these. How can I protect this without using SSL/HTTPS? I am guessing that the solution would consists of doing something both on client side and server side to take care of this. My server side is Java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use something like the [Secure Cookie Protocol (PDF)](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~alexliu/publications/Cookie/cookie.pdf) to encrypt the cookies prior to sending them.  Instead of the session identifier, you could use the requested IP address, or some other identifier that's 100% specific to the user in general.

So, to set it up, you'd create a server key `k`.  Then, you'd create the cookie as follows:

```
keyhmac = HMAC(user name + expiration time, k)
encrypted = ENCRYPT(data, keyhmac)
hmacenc = HMAC(user name + expiration time + data + session identifier, keyhmac)
cookie = user name + expiration time + encrypted + hmacenc;
```

Then, you can decrypt it later by using the reverse process.  The HMAC verifies that it was not tampered with outside your server (assuming that `k` is really secret)...

The fact that it includes a session identifier (SSL is best, but IP can possibly serve) means that it's immune to replay attacks or hijacking attacks.

SSL would be best, but you can get a pretty good system by using an encryption scheme such as this.  The absolute best would be combining this scheme with SSL, which then prevents all sorts of nasties (including MITM tampering, but not other MITM attacks)...

Comment: It says Secure Cookie Protocol requires SSL.

Comment: @Alan: That's how it was designed, yes.  But that's also why I said *something like*.  You can still get a significant benefit from encrypting the content in that manner even without SSL.  The best result is SSL.  But if you can't, you still can benefit...

Comment: @rook, can you either provide a beter solution, or at least explain what is wrong with this one?  Sure, SSL would be better, but given the parameters of the original question, what's wrong with this answer?

Comment: @ircmaxell  end-to-end transport layer protection such as that provided by SSL is the **only solution**.  In this case,  you are still transmitting a static value so that the client can authenticate to the server.  Nothing is stopping an eavesdropper from obtaining this value.   There are some JavaScript solutions, however the failure is that the original loading of the JavaScript code cannot be done in an authenticated fashion.

Comment: @ircmaxell Further more "Secure Cookie Protocol" is a gross misuse of cryptography because it is more secure and easier to use a simple cryptographic nonce as a cookie.   If you keep up on the news you'll have heard about the asp.net oracle padding vulnerability which shows that you can gain remote code execution on some web apps because of this misuse of cryptography.  "Complexity is the worst enemy of security" --Bruce Schneier

Comment: @ircmaxell you might also want to add the remote port to the ip since NAT'ed connections share the same IP.

Comment: Secure Cookie Protocol requires SSL.  Also requires a separate, secure session identifier known only to the server and the client (which sounds an awful lot like a cookie, which makes my head spin in infinite regression).  What an awful protocol.  WILL NOT WORK IN THIS SITUATION.

Answer (score 4):

Short Answer: no encryption means unencrypted data.

Longer Answer: If you want to encrypt your HTML stuff (and I include cookies and session id as HTML stuff), they you must encrypt your data.  You have two options: a. HTTPS or b. roll your own scheme.  Option b is almost never a good idea.

Comment: Is HTTPs solving almost all security issues for user authentication and API access by only authorized users?